# Preventing Credential Sharing

Tags: credentials

What technical methods can be implemented to force Nextcloud Pi users from sharing authentication credentials?  For example, In the military, this is halted with a certificates held in a smartchip in the ID (CAC) card.  Ideally users would have discentive to share a credential: credential resuse (FB / Google).

Update:  Maybe [EMV (Chip and PIN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMV) can be used as part of 2-factor authentication: I suspect most people not want to loan out their bank card.

Any edits to sharpen (reduce the scope) of the question is appreciated.

Comment: Nextcloud can do OpenID, OAuth2 and SAML so you can use any MFA provider which supports this.

Comment: Are you looking for a technical solution or a policy solution? Because credential sharing is very much a "people problem", so attempting to throw more tech at it will not work.

Comment: Agreed with MechMK1, you should take care of the proper side of the problem, which in your case is the users.

Comment: @MechMK1 For this exercise, a technical solution is to be explored.  Assume that users have been asked not to share credentials. If the existing tech is not effective, then "it is what it is"

Comment: Smart cards can be shared easily. If it's just a classroom exercise, then biometrics would probably be the best answer, assuming you're not worried about users creating fake fingers to share credentials.